# Is it necessary to manually add a ViewController.swift file after adding a new view controller in the story board?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbar

I am trying to build a tar bar app. I loaded the template of a two-tab app. Here is the [file tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0OaE.png)

```
-AppDelegate.swift
-FirstViewController.swift
-SecondViewController.swift
-Main.storyboard
```

As you can see, I have two ViewController.swift files. I added a new tab bar item in my storyboard and linked everything together. Everything works fine. I just want to make sure that this I do not need to manually add a ViewController.swift file for my third view since it is not there. Will this be problematic in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No.**

The ****ViewController.swift-files are there for you to be able to react to UI events like clicked buttons, shown / unshown views etc. In the InterfaceBuilder you **can** assign a ViewController to a view - you do not have to. If you do not set one, a default `UIViewController` will be used and assigned.

Without a custom one however you can not react to any events or change texts etc. BUT you can always come back later and then add a ViewController to do some customization.

A custom controller can be set by clicking on the top left icon of your view and specifying a different class than the default one:

[image]

Comment: how do I add a custom ViewController? I just create a file and name it after my view?

Comment: @JustinLéger added a screenshot

Comment: so I leave FirstViewController.swift and SecondViewController.swift untouched?

Comment: **Yes**. For now. If you want to add functionality you will have to touch them. Apart from that I don´t know what you are trying to achieve - the answer i gave does provide an answer to your question: it is not problematic not to specify and create a custom ViewController. Maybe you should ask a second question on SO if you have further questions.

Comment: Alright. Thanks you for you clear explanations. SO is awesome because of people like you!

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary. But if you want a custom behaviour for the third view you should create a new ViewController for it.